# How to vectorize an iteration over rows of tabular data

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have a tabular data set that is read from a file as a dataframe. The order of the rows is not relevant. The data has no single column that acts as a unique identifier of that row, but three or four of the columns could be combined to create a unique identifier for each item in that file.

I want to add a column to the dataframe with a categorical variable. The value for each row is derived by comparing one or more of the other values for that particular row. The values are all text so the operation can not be done arithmetically.

I am currently using a dataframe because it seems convenient but I have no particular attachment to the format and as mentioned previously, the order of the rows does not matter.

this is the function i want to apply to each row so i can generate a vector of values to bind to the dataframe as a new column

```
#input: line_item a single row from a dataframe with named columns
#output: a string
map_line_item_to_asset_class <- function(line_item){

  commodity <-  c('PHYSICAL INDEX FUTURE', 'PHYSICAL COMMODITY FUTURE','FINANCIAL COMMODITY FUTURE')
  equity <- c('ADR','COMMON STOCK', 'PFD', 'ETP', 'UNIT','REIT','EQUITY INDEX','EQUITY OPTION')
  fixed_income = c('ABS', 'CORP','SOVEREIGN DEBT','MUNI')
  other <- c('CASH')
  etp_fi_overrides <- c('EMLC')        

  asset_class <- line_item$INVESTMENT.TYPE
  if(line_item$INVESTMENT.TYPE %in% equity){
    asset_class <-'EQUITY'

    if(line_item$INVESTMENT %in% etp_fi_overrides)
      asset_class <- 'FIXED INCOME'
  } else{
    if(line_item$INVESTMENT.TYPE %in% fixed_income){
      asset_class <- 'FIXED INCOME'
    } else {
      if(line_item$INVESTMENT.TYPE %in% other) asset_class <- 'OTHER'
    } 
  }
  return(asset_class)
}
```

I know I could do this with by() or with a simple C-like for-loop using nrow(). That is how I am doing it now. I would like to know how, if at all, I would be able to vectorize this operation. I know that vectorization is generally preferred versus loop iteration, but I don't really know *how* the process of vectorizing something really works, i keep seeing the word and people telling others to do that, but I don't see examples of how to outside of stacking functions that already do that. Please note that I want to learn how to vectorize this as a learning exercise. I am fully aware that the CPU-time difference may be negligible in wall-clock time and that I can replicate the clean look using the applys. I want to know if and how to vectorize this specifically because it is an easy exercise and I would like how to do it properly when CPU time or memory *do* matter. Therefore telling me to just use a for loop or just use one of the applys won't really be helpful. (I am also aware of vectorize() and aware that it is also just syntax candy).

Comment: Have you read tutorials on how map / apply work? What don't you understand?

Comment: apply/mapply work by using loops under the surface. i know how apply works because that is currently what I am using, what I want to know is how to vectorize this function as a learning exercise.

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new function that just applies your current function over all the rows? That is the easiest solution

Comment: the whole point of this question is explicitly and only to learn a way to not do this

>Please note that I want to learn how to vectorize this as a learning exercise. I am fully aware that the CPU-time difference may be negligible in wall-clock time and that I can replicate the clean look using the applys. I want to know if and how to vectorize this specifically because it is an easy exercise and I would like how to do it properly when CPU time or memory do matter. Therefore telling me to just use a for loop or just use one of the applys won't really be helpful.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Is INVESTMENT.TYPE a column?

Comment: "apply/mapply work by using loops under the surface": the `purrr::map()` functions also run loops under the surface. Yet, they are considered as working in a vectorised fashion. See: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html

Comment: So my first reaction was to offer you a suggestion using `pmap()`. But if you are not happy with `apply()`, you will probably not consider this satisfactory.

Comment: So I am wondering whether you are hoping for something that does not exist: a functional programming approach, which is often indeed advised over writing for loops, will, under the hood, run a loop...

Comment: This could also be very useful for you: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html

Comment: thank you @prosoitos.I think my confusion stemmed over the fact that all the other answers I have seen to similar questions had a few responses with a simple "just vectorize it" with no clear indication of what that meant specifically or how precisely to do it. If I am reading this correctly, it seems like for this operation the loop/apply is the correct or only option. Knowing I *can't* vectorize it is a satisfactory answer,

Comment: @vengefulsealion it is a string. it is not a factor because new types could be introduced at any time in the future.

Comment: I suggest you read the chapters for which I posted links. They should clarify: 1. for loops vs functional programming, 2. the question of speed. As Hadley points out, for loops, if implemented correctly, are not slower. They are not recommended because it is hard to read the code. (Of course, ill-implemented, they also ARE dreadfully slow. He explains all this).

Comment: So it is indeed, a good idea to use the `apply()` of `purrr::map()` functions instead of writing for loops. But, if your loops are well built, you shouldn't see an improvement in speed. Only in style. And yes, they do run loops under the hood. I am not really sure what you mean by `vectorize`. I think that people use this as a shortcut to talk about functional programming.

Comment: "the loop/apply is the correct or only option": those are VERY different approaches. I really would not pool them together. `apply()` may run a loop under the hood, but the code will look dramatically different (and the way to think about the problem is also very different).

Comment: In short, what others were suggesting you do when they suggested that you "vectorize" was that you use one of the `apply()` or `map()` functions to apply a function to each element of a vector (or some variation of this).

Comment: True vectorization requires a computation that R can perform over one or more vectors without the use of a loop. For vectors `x <- 1:10` and `y <-  10:1`, the operation `x + y` would be vectorized, as R is able to add the vectors without looping over the single elements included in them. Specific R functions such as `rowSums` are implemented in a vectorized way. But, for many operations included in custom functions, vectorization is impossible without serious effort (like programming a solution in a different language and using it with the help of a package, e.g.`Rcpp`).

Comment: So, often enough when someone says 'just vectorize it', what the person means is 'use any form of `*apply()` function instead of a `for()` loop. This is obviously not a true vectorization, but will sometimes lead to quicker computation times because people tend to grow objects in `for()` loops, which is bad practice that can be avoided manually, but will automatically be avoided by using `*apply()`.

Comment: you should be aware that vectorization is not necessarily a for loop under the hood. In special cases modern CPUs can do SIMD instructions which is vectorization in hardware.

Comment: @LAP. Right, exactly. Plus the additional advantage of readability.